# An implication of linear independence of probability measures

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-distributions

Let $F_{1},..., F_{J}$ be some linearly independent probability measures over $\mathbb{R}$. I need to show that there exist some $h_{1},..., h_{J}$ measurable functions from $\mathbb{R}$ towards $\mathbb{R}$ such that the matrix $O = (\int_{\mathbb{R}}h_{i}dF_{j})_{1\leq i,j\leq J})$ is full rank. I thought of using wavelets or any elements of an orthogonal basis of $L^{2}(\mathbb{R})$ but I could not reach any satisfactory result.

Comment: If you make the problem a bit simpler by assuming there are PDFs $f_1, ..., f_J$ then you could write these PDFs according to an orthonormal basis using inner product $\langle f, g \rangle = \int f(x)g(x)dx$.

Comment: @Michael Thank you very much for your response. I see the trick.